# PMREM Generator size

Tags: three.js

Since 2016 threejs PBR can be based on PMREM cube textures which allows some great work. However the textures are hugely pixelated. How can one avoid that ?

In [this PR](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/8363) size definition as an argument of PMREM Generation was removed since the size of 256 was yet fixed in the shaders. But after replacing 1024 by 2048 at the beginning of `cube_uv_reflexion_fragment` nothing changed. No idea what else can be done.

How can one chose a better resolution for a pmrem envMap ?

Answer (score 1):

I had just forgotten to also change the value `this.resolution` in `PMREMGenerator.js` according to the quoted PR precisely.